# Stack Overflow on Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a function in my class that returns an array. Thing is, I get a Stack Overflow error when using. The important functions are:

ScrollList/returnArmy

```
    public function returnArmy ( army:int ):Array
    {
        var returnVar:Array;

        if( army == 0 ) returnVar = army1_;
        else if( army == 1 ) returnVar = army2_;
        else if( army == 2 ) returnVar = army3_;
        else if( army == 3 ) returnVar = army4_;
        else if( army == 4 ) returnVar = army5_;
        else if( army == 5 ) returnVar = army6_;
        else if( army == 6 ) returnVar = army7_;
        else if( army == 7 ) returnVar = army8_;
        else returnVar = new Array;

        return returnVar;
    }
```

SkirmishScreen/returnArmy

```
    public function returnArmy ( army_:int ):Array
    {
        var retArmy:Array = returnArmy( army_ );
        return retArmy;
    }
```

SkirmishScreen/returnArmy gets called in a loop, with

```
    screensAR_[3] = new PlayScreen( stage, screensAR_[2].returnArmy( 0 ) );
```

with army1_ to 8_ initialized with new Array().
Anyone can help?

EDIT: The precise error is:

Error: Error #1023: Stack overflow occurred.
    at SkirmishScreen/returnArmy()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with actionscript, but it looks like the "SkirmishScreen" returnArmy function is calling itself recursively, and never breaking out of it. This is a common source of stack overflow exceptions in other languages.

It doesn't appear like you mean to be using recursion. I'm guessing you want your "SkirmishScreen" returnArmy function to call the "ScrollList" returnArmy function, but instead the "SkirmishScreen" returnArmy is calling itself. That is recursion.

Comment: You are correct this is the problem.  var retArmy:Array = returnArmy( army_ ); has no breaking condition, if the function returns an existing array or a new array the method call to returnArmy is still made another time.  This will quickly create a stackoverflow of function calls.

Comment: I don't believe the OP should be using a recursive function call for this, it can just be a loop.

Comment: SkrimishScreen/returnArmy calls itself as the error points out.

Comment: It was never supposed to be a recursive function, it was meant as a wrapper to ScrollList's one, due to how the program is structured. Dang, this is why you don't program when sleep-deprived!